# Adiabatic mixing of liquids

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, energy, entropy

> One mole of benzene at $\pu{20^\circ C}$ is adiabatically mixed with 2 moles of toluene at $\pu{40^\circ C}$. The heat capacity of benzene is $\pu{84 J K-1 mol-1}$ and the heat capacity of toluene is $\pu{96 J K-1 mol-1}$. If benzene and toluene form an ideal solution, compute the entropy change for the process.

I tried to use

$$\Delta S = n C \ln{(T_\mathrm f/T_\mathrm i)}$$

where $C$ is the heat capacity and $T_\mathrm f$ and $T_\mathrm i$ are the final and initial temperatures of the liquids, respectively. However, I am unsure of what the final equilibrium temperature of the mixture comes to.

Comment: In addition to the temperatures of the liquids equilibrating (which results in an entropy change), you also need to include the entropy change due to mixing.

Comment: So what do you get for the entropy of mixing, and how does that compare with the entropy change due to heat transfer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let's say the final temperature is $T$. Also we assume the system is isolated and the process is adiabatic, as you said. Also all energy that is released by toluene or gained by benzene is heat.

The *absolute* amount of heat then released by toluene equals to the *absolute* amount of heat gained by benzene:

$|Q_\mathrm t| = |Q_\mathrm b|$

Considering signs, it will look like this:

$Q_\mathrm t = -Q_\mathrm b$

By definition, $Q = nc\Delta T$. Thus,

$Q_\mathrm t = 2\cdot96\cdot(40-T)$, and

$Q_\mathrm b = 1\cdot84\cdot(20-T)$

Plug in the latter two equations into the second one, and here's what you get:

$2\cdot96\cdot(40-T) = -1\cdot84\cdot(20-T)$

Now just solve it for $T$. And plug that in your equation as $T_\mathrm f$.

Note that it's not really important to do the temperature in kelvin, since we are dealing with changes in temperature. And yeap, your $T$ should be between $20\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$ and $40\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$, because there are such things as thermodynamics laws. So if it's not, you know for sure you did something not really correct.

Comment: This does not provide the complete solution to the problem.  The entropy of mixing also needs to be considered.

Comment: @ChesterMiller It's homework so not a problem usually.

Comment: The entropy of mixing still needs to be included.

Comment: @ChesterMiller how might one calculate the entropy of mixing, then?

Comment: @JonathanSmith well that's easily googleable https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_of_mixing